# Google forms approval workflow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to set up a workflow using Google Forms, Sheets and Apps Script. For a simple example lets say I am setting up a leave form for a company. I have a form for the employee enters their leave details. On submit the details are populated into a sheet and an email is sent to an someone for approval.

This is where I am getting stuck. What is the best way to approve the leave requests? I can just edit the sheet and once the column has been changed from *unapproved* to *approved* and email could be sent but I was hoping to avoid having to edit the sheet at all.

Is there a better way to handle this workflow?

Comment: The email sent to the reviewer could have a link to a second Google Form for the approval.  Another option would be to have some HTML in the email that would trigger a stand alone apps script file that finishes the process.  A link in an email can make a GET request to a `doGet()` function.  An HTML form can make a POST request to `doPost()`

Answer (score 1):

Assume that 3 people need to approve the request.  The approvers that need to review the request are approvers X,Y,Z.

- User X gets an Email requesting that they review the request
- The email that user X gets will use HTML
- The HTML will have a link in it
- A link in HTML submits a GET request
- Whenever you click a link, or enter a url into the browser address
  bar, a GET request is made to the url
- An Apps Script Web App is an Apps Script project that is published as
  a Web App
- A Web App has a url that can be used to make a request to it
- When the url (link) is used, a GET request is made
- A GET request made to an Apps Script Web App will run the doGet()
  function
- Once that doGet() function run, you can have your Apps Script code do
  anything that you want
- It can get information sent in to it from a search string
- Then send out another email to user Y
- So, when user X clicks the link, the url needs to have information
  appended to the url in the form of a search string

  httpz://the link?whichUser=X&approved=true

You can get the user and whether it was approved or not from the "event object" often designated by the letter "e"

```
function doGet(e) {
  var whatUserJustReviewed,isItApproved;

  //Get the values passed in from "e" which is the event object
  eventParam = e.parameter;
   whatUserJustReviewed  =  eventParam.whichUser;
  Logger.log(' whatUserJustReviewed    : ' +  whatUserJustReviewed    )

  isItApproved = eventParam. approved;


  switch (whatUserJustReviewed) {
    case "X"
    if (isItApproved  === 'true') {
      //    //Send an email to the next user which is Y
    }
    break;
    case "Y"
    if (isItApproved  === 'true') {
      //    //Send an email to the next user which is Z
    }
    break;
    case "Z"
    if (isItApproved  === 'true') {
      //Send an email to all involved who need to know that it was approved.
    }
    break;
   default:
      console.error('There was an error getting user or status');
  };


}
```